# Vagrant Multiple-VM Creation and Configuration error

Tags: debian, vagrant, virtual-machine, vagrantfile

Vagrant Multiple-VM Creation and Configuration error when running command "vagrant up" or "vagrant ssh" : It throws error message:

```
$ vagrant up
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:113:in `block (2 levels) in load': private method `load' called for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:107:in `each'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:107:in `block in load'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:104:in `each'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:104:in `load'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb:28:in `initialize'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:740:in `new'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:740:in `vagrantfile'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:486:in `host'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:208:in `block in action_runner'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `run'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:473:in `hook'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:722:in `unload'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/bin/vagrant:177:in `ensure in <main>'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/bin/vagrant:177:in `<main>'
```

my Vagrantfile is descripted  below, it uses shell scripts for installation and spinning puppet server machine and 2 nodes using virtualbox as VM and debian wheezy as Guest OS.Provisioning machine is giving some erratic error hard to debug, kindly resolve the issue. FYI, all files, nodes.json, boostrap-master.sh, bootstrap-node.sh,site.pp are lying along side of "Vagrantfile"

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.

##read vm and pupper configs from JSON files
  nodes_config = (JSON.parse(File.read("nodes.json")))['nodes']

VAGRANTFILE_API_v2 = "2"



Vagrant.configure("VAGRANTFILE_API_v2") do |config|
  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://atlas.hashicorp.com/search.
  config.vm.box = "debian/wheezy64"


  nodes_config.each do |node|
    node_name   = node[0] # name of node
    node_values = node[1] # content of node

    config.vm.define node_name do |config|
      # configures all forwarding ports in JSON array
      ports = node_values['ports']
      ports.each do |port|
        config.vm.network :forwarded_port,
          host:  port[':host'],
          guest: port[':guest'],
          id:    port[':id']
      end

      config.vm.hostname = node_name
      config.vm.network :private_network, ip: node_values[':ip']

      config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
        vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", node_values[':memory']]
        vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--name", node_name]
      end

      config.vm.provision :shell, :path => node_values[':bootstrap']
    end
  end
end




  # Disable automatic box update checking. If you disable this, then
  # boxes will only be checked for updates when the user runs
  # `vagrant box outdated`. This is not recommended.
  # config.vm.box_check_update = false

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  #  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, protocol:"tcp", auto_correct: true
  #  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, protocol:"udp", auto_correct: true
  #  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, protocol:"ssh", auto_correct: true   


  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  # config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  # config.vm.network "public_network"

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.

 # config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"

  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
  # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
  # Example for VirtualBox:
  #
  # config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  #   # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
  #   vb.gui = true
  #
  #   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
  #   vb.memory = "1024"
  # end
  #
  # View the documentation for the provider you are using for more
  # information on available options.

  # Define a Vagrant Push strategy for pushing to Atlas. Other push strategies
  # such as FTP and Heroku are also available. See the documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/push/atlas.html for more information.
  # config.push.define "atlas" do |push|
  #   push.app = "YOUR_ATLAS_USERNAME/YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME"
  # end

  # Enable provisioning with a shell script. Additional provisioners such as
  # Puppet, Chef, Ansible, Salt, and Docker are also available. Please see the
  # documentation for more information about their specific syntax and use.
  # config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
  #   apt-get update
  #   apt-get install -y apache2
  # SHELL
#end
```

For more deeper debugging mode log file is pasted here http://paste.ubuntu.com/17970100/

Comment: how is you JSon ? it seems to complain on node_values = node[1]

Comment: You can have JSON file look here [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/17973509/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did not review everything but all comes with

```
Vagrant.configure("VAGRANTFILE_API_v2") do |config|
```

as you declare a variable you need to call

```
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_v2) do |config|
```

as you write you call the method with argument _VAGRANTFILE_API_v2_ not the value of the argument.